# Will the electric field surrounding the poles of a battery change if we connect the poles with a conducting wire?

Tags: electric-fields

Around a battery (the poles disconnected), an electric field exists. If we connect the poles with a wire, a current starts to flow in such a way that the electric field inside the wire is always parallel to the wire (so the wire takes care that the current doesn't flow along an electric field line produced by the battery). How looks the electric field surrounding the battery, in this case, compared to the surrounding electric field of a battery whose poles are disconnected?
Will the field stay the same? Or are electric field lines "taken away" by the wire from the surrounding electric field so that the density of field lines inside the wire becomes higher than the density of field lines if the wire were not there? I can't exactly see how, but I'm not sure.

Answer (score 1):

As current is drawn from a battery, the potential difference between the terminals drops due to the effective internal resistance of the battery. (The chemical reaction can't keep up with the demand.) The charge on the terminals (and the associated field) will also drop.  The charge density along the conductor will vary in a manner that  maintains a constant current flow.

Comment: Does this mean that there is no electric field surrounding the battery anymore? I mean, there is still a voltage inside the battery, which causes an electric field to exist around the battery.

Comment: The highest charge density is still at the terminals of the battery.

Comment: But there is no voltage anymore between the terminals. Isn't a voltage require to make an electric field? Or will the inner voltage of the battery make up the outside electric field?

Comment: If the resistance of your external wire is very low, the internal resistance of the battery will determine the maximum current flow, but you still need some voltage at the terminals to drive a large current through the small external resistance.  The fields from the terminals will be small, but not zero. (One method of  checking the health of a battery is to measure the short circuit current.)

Comment: Doesn't the highest charge density exist inside the battery?

Comment: The chemical reaction moves electrons to the negative terminal.